# Effectively training multiple formations

Tags: football-manager-2017

The answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292027) suggests that it's difficult to run two formations where all players are in a comfortable role/position. However, my assistant manager keeps insisting that we train two or more different formations.

What is the best solution here? To run two different formations, try and get a good average comfort rating, and accept that some players will not be playing to the best of their ability? Run two otherwise identical formations with different instructions (e.g. control/counter, high/low tempo)? Or just ignore my assistant manager, and dedicate all efforts to a single formation/tactic?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the same tactic in all three slots if you want to, this will also help your players to learn it faster.

I tend to do this, just to stop the Assistant manager moaning.